# Variance of the pre-trained word embeddings trained by word2Vec (Google News Corpus)

Tags: gensim, word2vec

How can i compute the variance of the pre-trained word embeddings trained by word2Vec in gensim?
In need the variance for the word2Vec-model trained by google (Google News corpus).
Thanks.